# how to populate users object with field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

These the response for `user` that Im getting from get request to profile API

```
"user": "5cc3a4e8d37a7259b45c97fe"
```

What I'm looking for instead is

```
"user":{
    "_id": "5cc3a4e8d37a7259b45c97fe",
    "name":"Jhon Doe",

}
```

Here is my code:

```
Profile.findOne({ 
        user: req.user.id
    })
    .populate('user',['name']) // I added this line to populate user object with name
    .then(profile=>{
        if(!profile){
            errors.noprofile = 'There is no profile for this user'
            return res.status(404).json(errors);
        } 
            res.json(profile)

    })
    .catch(err => res.status(404).json(err));
```

However, Im getting these error:

```
{
    "message": "Schema hasn't been registered for model \"users\".\nUse mongoose.model(name, schema)",
    "name": "MissingSchemaError"
}
```

What am I missing

Profile Schema

```
const ProfileSchema = new Schema({
    user:{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'users'
    },
    handle: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        max: 40
    },
    company: {
        type: String
    },
    website: {
        type: String,
    }
})
```

Here is how my Users schema looks like

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Schema

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    email:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    password:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    avator:{
        type: String,

    },
    date:{
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
    }
});



module.exports = User = mongoose.model('Users', UserSchema)
```

Comment: Could you share with us `Profile` and `user` schema?

Comment: Please show us your `Profile` object - I'm guessing it's just not mapped correctly..

Comment: @IvanVasiljevic I have updated the Schema

Comment: @gillyb checkout my update

Comment: @toymoy thanks. I see that Ivan Vasiljevic already answered your question correctly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Schema that you are referencing in `Profile` schema is `users`, but you have saved your user schema as `Users`. So I would say that you need to update your `Profile` schema:

```
const ProfileSchema = new Schema({
    user:{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Users'
    },
    handle: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        max: 40
    },
    company: {
        type: String
    },
    website: {
        type: String,
    }
})
```

Name under which is saved your `User` schema can be found in this line

```
module.exports = User = mongoose.model('Users', UserSchema)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says you don't have Schema for Users. You reference it from Profile Schema, but you don't have it. It can be this way:

```
const Users = new Schema({
    name: String
})
```